# Python regex with exclusion of a character

Tags: python, regex

Having a list of texts:

```
l=["SOMETHING","SOME_1","SOM_1"]
```

I am looking for a regex pattern to match the first string, but not the second one:

- return `TRUE` if the text starts with 'SOM' , possible some other characters, *and no underscores*;
- by consequence, return `FALSE` if the text starts with 'SOM' and contains at least one underscore (somewhere inside the text, it does not matter where that underscore is)

This is what I tried, but does not work:

```
import re
l=["SOMETHING","SOME_1","SOM_1"]
find_pattern=re.compile("^SOM[A-Z]*[^_]")
for s in l:
    print bool(find_pattern.match(s))
```

I am expecting:

```
True
False
False
```

But I think the multiplication operand is not correct, because I get:

```
True
True
False
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re
l=["SOMETHING","SOME_1","SOM_1"]
find_pattern=re.compile("^SOM[^_]*$")
for s in l:
    print bool(find_pattern.match(s))
```

Prints the expected result:

```
True
False
False
```

---

In the pattern, note the importance of the `$` anchor. If this was not present, you would receive false positives.

Comment: Starts with "som", followed by 0 or more characters which are not "_". My initial code  was forcing an letter between "som" and "_". I see where I was wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
find_pattern = re.compile('^SOM[^_]*(?!\_)$')

for s in l:
    print(bool(find_pattern.match(s)))

# True
# False
# False
```

Sample and explanation here: https://regex101.com/r/DVzoww/1

Comment: I believe the asker is on Python 2.

Comment: `print(...)` is valid syntax in Python 2 as well, but noted.

Comment: I just noticed my negative lookahead is redundant, and it basically boils down to the same answer as yours.

Comment: True, I am in python 2; and true, `print (...)` works in python 2. This also works fine, but I am choosing the other answer simply because it is more in line with the straightforward texts I am dealing with